# How to trace the requests from One .Net Web App to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httprequest, webrequest

Is that possible to trace the web request..??

I have two web applications running on same IIS web server. I need to know the frequency of their communication between each other..

For Example ..

If i have 'X' and 'Y' web apps. Initially from a web browser i send request to "X" .. "X" do request to 'Y' ..

In the above case, I need to trace to which app "X" is sending requesting and also from which app request is coming to "Y".

Is this identification possible in the "X" and "Y" , if they are two .Net web applications running in same IIS web server.

**Update-1:** I am using .Net framework 4.5 and both X and Y are the web applications running on IIS web server. Both the apps are not using MVC. But Eager to know how it can be got even at the case of MVC framework too..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find some really useful information within the IIS logs on your web server, located at C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1. For example you can get the source of a request. A typical file consists of the following information:

#### Date: 2013-10-02 09:31:23

#### Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2013-10-02 09:31:23 10.22.22.162 GET /WebsiteBlah/somerandompage.aspx - 8080 - 10.89.2.227 - 401 2 5 203

Right at after the date time, you get the source IP. Assuming that X and Y run on a different port or IP then you should be able to identify where your calls come from

Comment: Thanks ..! But can i get this inside the X and Y ..?? Say i have some code to get this inside Page_Init() of Y ? Basically my question is Will that be known inside the Web apps Runtime..??

Comment: You may be able to capture the request headers, however you have not explained what framework you use (mvc, webapi, webforms) so I cannot give you more information now. Can you elaborate a bit more about the implementation details?

Comment: I have updated my question above.. Kindly check that for the details..!

Comment: You could try using the `HttpRequest.UrlReferrer` to got the origin of the request. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx